# For a 1-action spell, do I need to take a turn to ready the spell before I can cast it, or can I cast it immediately?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

I am still very new to all of D&D 5e's rules.

Let's say I have a wizard that knows *fireball*; he has the spell prepared and has an available spell slot. Basically, assume ideal for everything.

Do I have to take a turn to "ready" the spell, then cast it the next turn? Or can I cast it right then and there?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, preparing the spell is all the readying you need. When you want to cast the spell, you just wait for your turn, and then say that you cast it. Boom, you just fireballed some goblins, who now all have to make Dexterity saving throws. (Hopefully you and/or your DM will describe the action a little better than I have.)

Doing that costs you the spell slot, so you have to mark down on your sheet that you used, for example, a 3rd-level spell slot and you have one fewer of those until you get a long rest. It also costs you “1 action,” which basically means “the one big thing you’re doing this turn,” since you get one action per turn. In addition to your “action,” during your turn you can also move before and/or after acting, and you can manipulate some item (draw, or sheathe, or whatever). You may also have options that require a “bonus action,” which (as the name suggests) can be done in addition to your action, but again, only one of those per turn. Also, you cannot cast any other non-cantrip spell in the same turn as a bonus-action spell.

Comment: @Gabe: You may want to review the rules of spellcasting in chapter 10 of the PHB/basic rules: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting

Comment: "Also, you can only cast one non-cantrip spell per turn" - This is not accurate. The rule is if you cast a bonus action spell the only other spell you can cast on your turn is a cantrip. For example, I could trigger an Attack of Opportunity, use my reaction to cast Shield if the enemy hits me, and then use an Action to cast another spell. So long as I don't use a bonus action spell, I'm not limited in how many spells I can cast. If I was multi-classed Fighter, I could also action surge and cast a 2nd action spell.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli OK, sure, in that contrived case you could cast two non-cantrip spells. And I suppose if there is a bonus-action cantrip, you’d get to cast zero non-cantrip spells (barring a contrived reaction). I’ll fix it.

Comment: Just to be pedantic/thorough: "And I suppose if there is a bonus-action cantrip, you’d get to cast zero non-cantrip spells (barring a contrived reaction)." - Reactions can happen on your turn, too (e.g. moving away from an enemy and casting Shield to make the opportunity attack miss, or Counterspelling an enemy's Counterspell)... So if you cast any bonus action spell, you can't cast any reaction spell on that same turn either.

Comment: @V2Blast Such a weird and arbitrary rule...

Comment: Yeah, It really is.

Comment: @KRyan I'm pretty sure it's intended to stop you from casting a regular Fireball followed by a Quickened Fireball as a Bonus Action.

Comment: Really great answering with simplifying the rules into a much more understandable prose. You may want to consider adding links to the basic rules for each piece so they can go back and match your description to the written.

Answer (score 6):

You are able to cast it then and there, assuming all conditions have been met (can speak, move at least one hand, and have bat guano & sulfur or an arcane focus). As it has a casting cost of one action, you need only recite the chant, make the required movements, and spend the material (or get an arcane focus and safe on a lot of time). The spell will then be activated.